# How do I handle a co-worker stealing company time?

Tags: software-industry, colleagues

My co-worker and I started at the same time, mid-summer, so we each have 9 days of vacation time through the end of the year. Our new boss works remotely and there is very little accountability. My co-worker has started missing a lot of work lately. Sometimes he'll email the team and give some medical excuse (sometimes telling me a different excuse--like just being tired or out with friends), but most of the time, he doesn't send out an email at all, just hopes nobody notices. He's up to 23 days off, but he's not reporting all those days. I talked to my manager about it a couple weeks ago and he said that he was trying to give leniency to this employee because of his medical issues, because he doesn't know that they aren't as valid as he thinks. I feel like I've done all I can do by talking to the manager about it, but it's getting out of hand. He hasn't been to work in a couple weeks, and my manager doesn't seem to care at all. Is there anything else I can do about it?

Comment: I bet a few days off would help your mood considerably! Seriously though, let your manager do their job.

Comment: Are you paid by the hour and/or bill client's for time? Does his absence require others to do his work? What's the real problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I talked to my manager about it a couple weeks ago and he said that he was trying to give leniency to this employee because of his medical issues

That obviously is your first step and you've done it. You're not a manager and more specifically, you're not **his manager**. For you to do more would be stepping on your manager's toes, big time.

> I feel like I've done all I can do by talking to the manager about it, but it's getting out of hand.

You're right, you have done all you can do since that's really the only thing you should do. So having said that, they only thing you have left that you can actually do is approach your manager one more time and let him know the specifics of your concerns. Be aware though that this may annoy your manager and may backfire, but if you're determined to do *something*, there's really not much else you should do. Anything more than this (such as going over his head) could well up with you ending up looking like a great big troublemaker, and looking worse than your coworker, possibly even looking jealous because he's "getting away" with something.

If you do decide to approach your manager, I'd start out by saying that you feel really strongly about it and felt you had to say something else but that this is the last you'll say on the subject.

Think about what you're saying though and be careful. You're essentially saying that you're manager is incompetent and that you would be a better manager than he is because you would handle it. If we can make that assessment, I'm sure your manager will too.

Tread very lightly.

Answer (score 7):

If you feel that you still need to approach your boss about this, then you need to talk about **how this is affecting you**. Is the absence of your coworker making it difficult for you to do your own work? How is this impacting the team and project? Don't say that the coworker needs to be punished or investigated - just talk about how to improve your ability to do your job. This might mean redistributing your coworker's tasks, or maybe hiring someone to fill in the gaps. If your boss determines that your coworker needs to come into the office more, then that is management's decision, not yours.

If your coworker's absence is not affecting your work, and really just bothers you for the principle of it, then **let it go**. You have alerted management that there might be something up, and you are still able to do your job, so the ball isn't in your court anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Is this worker causing you to miss deadlines?  If not, just let it go.

Comment: They are putting the whole team behind schedule, and not only that, but I care about my company and this employee has stolen thousands of dollars from taking extra days off.

Comment: @user29405: That's something for management to deal with. NOT YOU. Do your own job to the best of your abilities and let the company decide what to do about the individual. The "extra" days off may be manager-authorized, may be sick time, may be flex time, may already be reflected in their paycheck -- IT'S NOT YOUR ROLE TO MAKE ANY OF THOSE DECISIONS. Management is aware of the issue. Management is dealing with it. LET GO and pay attention to your own work.

Comment: @keshlam I've talked to the co-worker, and he said that he has not reported the time, and that his paychecks haven't changed. Management is aware that the employee took extra days off, but doesn't know the extent of it.

Comment: Unless you own the company it's not "your company" you're just another resource or billable hour to a time sheet.  

Him steeling isn't directly impacting you.  If it's making you miss deadlines then you bring up at meeitngs that the schedule is slipping and need to find a way to resolve the matter

Comment: If the employee is delivering, their schedule isn't your problem. If the employee isn't delivering, it's management's job to take this up with them. NOT YOURS. This is not a zero sum game; making them look bad will _not_ make you look better. Doing your own work better is what will make you look better.

Comment: I disagree with "just letting it go." Why is one employee entitled to 23 days off with pay if others are not?

Comment: Because this employee isn't responsible for personnel decisions or time policies.

Comment: Because you don't know if your friend is being paid for those days be Missed

Comment: @Ramhound I do know that my friend is getting paid for those days. He has told me. He's been very honest about it with me. There may not be much I can do about it, but I do know all the facts, and it isn't fair. I'm still doing all my work, and I haven't mentioned anything more to the manager, but it's hard not to be frustrated by it.